# What is the appropriate loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

My current code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
    System.out.print("*");
```

but the output is:

```
***
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
***  
**#  
*##  
###
```

Am I using the appropriate loop or is it something to do with my loop parameters or loop body?
The only solution that I can think of is multiplying a string but that is impossible of course.

Comment: Post your complete code !!!

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, but as a hint I would just say that you need a loop inside another loop.

Comment: your code doesnt  even print `***` it prints `****`

Comment: I bet you could do it without any loops at all (via recursion). Not pretty, but you don't *need* two loops.

Comment: using two nested  loops is not the only way.but for beginner and  it's the simple one

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 3;
for(int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        if(j < index) {
            System.out.print("*");                  
        } else {
            System.out.print("#");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    index--; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a single for loop, you can do it as follows:

```
char[] tmp = new char[3];
java.util.Arrays.fill(tmp, 0, 3, '*');
String stars = new String(tmp);  // stars is now "***"
java.util.Arrays.fill(tmp, 0, 3, '#');
String hashes = new String(tmp); // hashes is now "###"

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i) {
  System.out.println(
    stars.substring(0, 3 - i)  // 3 - i '*' characters
        + hashes.substring(0, i)  // i '#' characters
  );
}
```

I believe this is along the lines of what you might have meant by 'multiplying' the string.